# Truncating all tables in MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I want to execute this MySQL command:

```
mysql -Nse 'show tables' DATABASE_NAME | while read table; do mysql -e "truncate table $table" DATABASE_NAME; done
```

Whenever I do so, I receive the following [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRLQ3.png):

> 'WHILE' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Check the other answers in the duplicate topic, not just the accepted one. Btw your script is not for windows command line, this is why it does not run.

Comment: But all are giving single table truncation.

Comment: But I need all tables truncation

Comment: Nope, the other solutions also truncate all tables.

Comment: Thank You Friend.You have any other solution share with me.